# Hide div after sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, show-hide

I have Google Maps with properties pins, and a search box below it. After the user clicks on "sort", pins are shown based on user's criteria. I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to hide the search box, and only leave the box "Show search", instead of "Sort".

Here is the image how it currently looks:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/87SQo.jpg

And here is part of the search box code:

```
<div class="main-search">           
    <form id="main-search" method="post" action="#">
        <!-- search box fields here -->
        <input type="submit" value="Sort" class="search-submit" id="search-submit" />          
    </form>     
</div>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple demo is at http://jsfiddle.net/xekR9/1/.

Don't forget to change `return false` to `return true` to allow [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) post.

Comment: I haven't seen that you used my demo code in your code. Did you tried my demo? It hides all child elements of the form except your sort button and changes its label to Show search. But remember you can't hide form element, because it's the parent element of sort button. If parent element is hidden, then its children will be hidden anyway.

Comment: Once again, thanks a bunch :)
Yes, i did, but i missed the "$(this).val("Show search");" so it didnt worked.Now it works, but i after i click on "Show search" nothing happens, search isnt shown.
But nevermind, thank you for all your help!
Enjoy your sunday

Comment: Thank you. But in your question you only wanna show "Show search" button. You did not tell us what function this button performs. Or do you mean nothing happens after clicking "Sort" button? Then as I said you just replace return false in my js code with return true, which enables PHP POST. I used return false, because jsfiddle.net does not allow PHP POST.

Comment: I replaced return false with return true for you. http://jsfiddle.net/KNZ6d/2/    Run this code in your browser instead of directly in jsfiddle.net. Good luck!

Comment: Hey once again!
Sorry for the delay, i was little busy  :\
Take a look at http://tinyurl.com/bpcheft (password "marinero"), and you will see what i mean.Click on Villa in the search box (only one item on the map), and click on "sortirajte".That property is shown properly, but i cant restore the search box by clicking on the "Show search".About PHP code, i guess it pulls objects from DB, i dont know, since i havent worked that...

Comment: In $(document).ready(function(){                                             }); You add: $("input[value='Show search']").on('click', function(){
    $("form#main-search").find(":not(.search-submit)").show();
    $(this).text('Sortirajte');
});

Comment: I added it inside the function you told me, but nothing happens, search box "hiddes", but it cant be displayed it "show search" is clicked  :\ http://jsfiddle.net/KNZ6d/3/

Comment: Sry I made a mistake last time. Please try:          $("input.search-submit").on("click", function(){
    // Hide other controls except sort button
    if($(this).val() == 'Sortirajte') {        
        $("form#main-search").find(":not(.search-submit)").hide();
        $(this).val("Show search");        
    }
    // Show the hidden controls
    else if($(this).val() == 'Show search') {        
            $("form#main-search").find(":not(.search-submit)").show();                    
            $(this).val('Sortirajte');        
    }
    return true; 
}); DELETE line 52-61 in neum.info

Comment: If it still does not work, please write me an email. My email address: albrecht.jun.zhang@gmail.com

Comment: Sry, please delete from line 52 to line 64 including 64.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean to leave the show search, but to hide the button do this:

```
$('.search-submit').on('click',function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Nothing, same as on the code snipped above...I meant, after the user clicks on sort, search box dissapears, and instead of "Sort" button, there is "Show search" button...Does that make sense? :\

Comment: Shows pins on the map that match the users search (if user choose "hotels" from the search, only the hotels are displayed)